# Xamarin.Forms detecting vertical/horizontal zoom on chart

Tags: charts, xamarin.forms, zooming

I am using XF and sfchart and I want to detect the zooming direction and set the zoom mode based on it, I mean if the user starts zooming vertically I want to zoom mode to be set on Y axis and when they zoom horizontally I want to set it on X axis. Is there anyway to detect the zoom direction?